# ProgressDialog(context) in AsyncTask causes Error "Activity has leaked window"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am trying to convert a Fragment to Activity and am running into a bit of trouble.
I have 3 activities that are run with use of Intents:

```
MainActivity -> DetailsActivity -> MyPagerActivity
```

PagerActivity does some UI work and calls an AsyncTask at the end to send some data to my server. My ASyncTask is in a separate Java file and I call the function with "MyPagerActivity.this" as context:

```
NetFuncs nu = new NetFuncs();
...
nu.FinishWork(MyPagerActivity.this, workData1, WorkData2);
```

In the NetFuncs:

```
private Context mContext;
....
public void FinishWork(Context context, String Data1, long Data2) {
     if (networkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
        new FinishWorkServerCall(context, Data1, Data2).execute();
     }
private class FinishWorkServerCall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public class FinishWorkServerCall (Context context, String Data1, long Data2) {
        mContext = context;
        ...
   }
   @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mcontext);
                pDialog.setMessage("Finishing your work...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
     ....
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if ( pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }
```

In the Fragment world everything worked beautifully. As soon as I moved to a standalone activity, right at pDialog.show(); the app crashes with the following error:

```
Activity com.example.MyPagerActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{7acbcb8 V.E...... R......D 0,0-1026,348} that was originally added here
```

I googled a lot and everyone kept talking about dismissing in postExecute() and in onDestroy() and I am doing both of those but it is not helping.
I think the problem is a context problem but I don't know what the problem could be and how to fix it. I have used getApplicationContext(), getBaseContext(), none worked.
I used Toast() instead and same issue, so I am guessing it is a contetx issue.

***EDIT:***
My MyPagerActivity does not close or finish while pDialog is in progress. It stays up.

Can someone please help me figure out what the issue is and help find a solution?

Thank you

Comment: Add you complete log trace.

Comment: add the code of FinishWork call in fragment

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in try/catch block:

```
try {
   pDialog.show();
} cath (Exception ignored) {
   // do nothing, activity keeps working
}
```

P.S. it is a "hack" but the problem still is here. Ussualy, "has leaked window" happens, when your Activity recreates during AsyncTask works. You can try to dismiss porgress if it is showing in onDestroy() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class FinishWorkServerCall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public class FinishWorkServerCall (Context context, String Data1, long Data2) {
        mContext = context;
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mcontext);
        pDialog.setMessage("Finishing your work...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
   }
   @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
                if (pDialog != null) {
                    pDialog.show();
                }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I think I just found a solution:
I added a handler:

```
        h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        h.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mcontext);
                pDialog.setMessage("Finishing your work...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();

            }
        });
```

and did the pDialog inside the handler. It solved the problem of crashing...not sure why but it does. Can someone help me understand why this may be?